# How to handle <form> data received by http server e.g (key=value&key=value&key=value&...) using C language and assign each value to a variable?

Tags: c, http, post, server, response

I have http server running on a microcontroller. It serves a short html web page that contains a form. Once I fill the form and click submit using POST method, I receive the form values as follows:

`Key1=value1&Key2=value2&Key3=value3&...`

The whole data received is saved as a string inside a buffer.

The question is: how can I handle this data by saving each key=vale in a variable. e.g:

`int key1 = value1
int key2 = value2 
int key3 = value3`

Thank you very much

Comment: You will need to *parse* the string using the very limited parsing capability standard C library is providing, or by using some third party provided libraries. Ah, and no, you won't be able to define variables named after the substrings.

Comment: You could save this in a hash. Are the key _names_ known and fixed, and the number of them fixed as well? If so, an array of two element structs would do it. The buffer could be parsed with `strtok` with delimiters of "&". This gives you a _single_ `key=val`. You can then use `strchr` on this to find the `=` and split the string into two: `key` and `value`

Comment: @CraigEstey Thank you very much for your reply. Yes, the key values and the number of them are known. However, I reached until this point but I don't know what to do inside the while loop and where to use the strchr function. Sorry I am a beginner and your help is very appreciated. 

`typedef struct keyPlusValue {
char *key 
int value } keyPlusValue_t;`
 
`char buffer = "key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3";`
`char *token = strtok(buffer, "&");` 
`while (token != NULL) { 

token = strtok(NULL, "-"); 
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is prefaced by my top comments.

Here's a full implementation with test cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum {
    KEY1,
    KEY2,
    KEY3
};

typedef struct keyPlusValue {
    char *key;
    int value;
} keyPlusValue_t;

keyPlusValue_t symlist[] = {
    [KEY1] = { "key1", 0 },
    [KEY2] = { "key2", 0 },
    [KEY3] = { "key3", 0 },
};

int symcount = sizeof(symlist) / sizeof(symlist[0]);

void
parse_list(const char *str)
{
    char buf[strlen(str) + 1];
    char *bp;
    char *tok;
    char *val;
    keyPlusValue_t *symtry;
    keyPlusValue_t *symok;

    // NOTE: we _must_ create a copy of the string because caller could pass
    // in a constant string and we are going to _write_ into our copy
    strcpy(buf,str);

    bp = buf;
    while (1) {
        // get next "key=val" pair
        tok = strtok(bp,"&");
        if (tok == NULL)
            break;
        bp = NULL;

        // split up pair into "key" and "value"
        val = strchr(tok,'=');
        if (val == NULL) {
            printf("malformed token -- '%s'\n",tok);
            break;
        }
        *val++ = 0;

        // scan symbol/key table looking for match
        symok = NULL;
        for (symtry = symlist;  symtry < &symlist[symcount];  ++symtry) {
            if (strcmp(tok,symtry->key) == 0) {
                symok = symtry;
                break;
            }
        }

        // if no match found -- should not happen but _must_ be checked for
        if (symok == NULL) {
            printf("unknown key -- '%s'\n",tok);
            break;
        }

        // convert text representation of number into int
        symok->value = atoi(val);
    }
}

void
test(const char *str)
{
    keyPlusValue_t *sym;

    printf("\n");
    printf("test: '%s'\n",str);

    parse_list(str);

    for (sym = symlist;  sym < &symlist[symcount];  ++sym)
        printf(" key='%s' val=%d\n",sym->key,sym->value);
}

int
main(void)
{

    test("key1=1&key2=2&key3=3");
    test("key1=2&key2=3&key3=4");
    test("key1=3&key2=4&key3=5");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are only a fixed set of keys you are ever interested in, then you likley want a table that associates the the keys to the corresponding variables. As an example:

```
enum { Key1, Key2, Key3 /* ... */};
struct {
    const char *key;
    int value;
} key_table[KEY_TABLE_SZ] = {
    [Key1] = { "Key1", INT_MIN },
    [Key2] = { "Key2", INT_MIN },
    [Key3] = { "Key3", INT_MIN },
    /* ... */
};
```

As you parse your query parameter string, and you identify the keys, you can then do a lookup into your table to set the value into the associated variable.

```
const char *key;
const char *value;
char *query_string2 = strdup(query_string);
char *rest = query_string2;
while ((rest = parse_query_string(rest, &key, &value)) != NULL) {
    int i = key_table_find(key);
    if (i == -1) {
        /* ... unknown key ... */
        continue;
    }
    key_table[i].value = strtol(value, 0, 10);
}
free(query_string2);
```

Then, the value you are interested in can be indexed by the enumeration.

```
if (key_table[Key1] != INT_MIN) {
    /* ... do something with Key1 ... */
}
```

Parsing a parameter string can be done with a call to `strchr` and `strchrnul`. (If your system lacks `strchrnul`, it is just like `strchr`, except if the search character isn't found, it returns a pointer to the `'\0'` at the end of the string instead of `NULL`.)

```
char * parse_query_string(char *rest, const char **key, const char **value) {
    char *p, *q;
    if ((p = rest) == NULL || (q = strchr(p, '=')) == NULL) return NULL;
    *q++ = '\0';
    if (*(rest = strchrnul(q, '&'))) *rest++ = '\0';
    *key = p;
    *value = q;
    return rest;
}
```

Note that the enumeration values can be initialized to appropriate hash values to speed up the find operation.

```
enum {
    Key1 = KEY_TABLE_HASH('K', 'e', 'y', '1'),
    Key2 = KEY_TABLE_HASH('K', 'e', 'y', '2'),
    Key3 = KEY_TABLE_HASH('K', 'e', 'y', '3'),
    /* ... */
};
```

Below is a hypothetical implementation of the hash. It can only handle strings up to 5 bytes in length, but it should be relatively straight forward to extend it to longer strings (up to the maximum macro nesting level supported on your system).

```
#define HASH(...)         HASH_(UP_TO_5(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
#define HASH_(...)        HASH__(__VA_ARGS__)
#define HASH__(N, ...)    HASH_##N(2166136261U, __VA_ARGS__)

#define HASH_5(H, A, ...) HASH_4(HASH_1(H, A), __VA_ARGS__)
#define HASH_4(H, A, ...) HASH_3(HASH_1(H, A), __VA_ARGS__)
#define HASH_3(H, A, ...) HASH_2(HASH_1(H, A), __VA_ARGS__)
#define HASH_2(H, A, ...) HASH_1(HASH_1(H, A), __VA_ARGS__)
#define HASH_1(H, A)      (((H) ^ (unsigned)(A)) * 16777619U)

#define UP_TO_5(...) UP_TO_5_(__VA_ARGS__, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
#define UP_TO_5_(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, X, ...) X

#define KEY_TABLE_HASH(...) HASH(__VA_ARGS__) % KEY_TABLE_SZ
enum { KEY_TABLE_SZ = 11 };
```

And the find function is implemented using the same hash algorithm.

```
int key_table_find(const char *key) {
    unsigned hash = 2166136261U;
    const char *p = key;
    while (*p) {
        hash = HASH_1(hash, *p);
        ++p;
    }
    hash %= KEY_TABLE_SZ;
    if (key_table[hash].key == 0) return -1;
    if (strcmp(key_table[hash].key, key) != 0) return -1;
    return hash;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVVtc9pGEP6uX7GFAe5kmSDJxtNQOkM7npCxSzqxadM67g1BZ6OJOEAvyXgafru7dzpJJ8C1Z6IPoFs9z748uyvNj@/n88dmwO9CwYG9mUzZ1bvp@1/PrWYo5lEWcPgpSeNQ3HcXP1vNTCCyBqvhgnClYKYpCj/VbVG4DNMEbWXY8ehqTLrdLoXikhZGpr@z63fslDD2x4iN3r@5Yow6YJ4s0wWr@VAWRp5GMzJxoGAoS7M5IZ7b77t@3@u7051QdfYpGTsw0g6U5YSoP1c9@N88T/a4/ou5/h7XezHX2@O6L@ZqSK4tIWRM4R8gmUjCe8EDSkaUgg1u/@zsrO/@ODXkKrqooupDrS8OnDpw4oDvgOeAS3eZCHYxNXzGEMIQyZDwQdfxoYp0cf4Xux79cnnOqolSd2ZZ0DJwV39bFhfZEv6tGWEIrgvbgX5myZov@IOL9p0YnYuOAx0ufx7kj9uhTgH3nod7Btx/Hu4X8Fe2LB7sVxYmaeGCZvNU5zlfiSSF@WIWg/2ZPwyUMRQpfJlFGR9YW0ArS2efIn5j1nyL4XMPN7JUdYSGvG048HZyzX57O4GtUyK8CuEdRvgVwt9H1EvABK0yL4bdDMhOIVRnV4wcLGbJAgMYCzvYE2CNgFKEr4sw4kDsdeFKXtqLnnF5cpBGByXg6GidH7ZWiW8Na@OiNb4DUkkrcbddPMNwCD0KMU@zWMCxW4GxbfPl@hDHAVXwD4eY@iix2EzLygu11rM44WyT8fiB5S9skj@JeZI6NVFsFaFmUbNRyKKlQx02VbJESil9UVnQZHp5Cd@@AdmgVdaxiAkSOsMOLZ/TUkKdsjTmDu3N0RESOx97nSqCTaT70p/IIrJBl210WblS5eyQbaUy6DblteB5U9NL8lCvR7kJy1kogHxZhQE9sDSmhuhGrcDQ7bntMY@i1fDPVRwFbTnTQ7/nNwZPL51p1MtXyWtG8fKig2xNTDM18VqbGq021oV6BwYhH4G2ans7b7UaLtUlYxekNmG@MeYiylms9kG2KpQ9PnZNrrzWGC29I41MfBarryJPViY0W/KUx8i7F6sYvxavoVEj6quBkYY3reQ2f1ep24@iobbByW1GIlriNBSFstWWyqvaq/C2WwwFKpKuIqKODvTwc9Oj5nrfxZzXmuDRQ9ut3pDaKQqpX23VmBZKtJLX0AqKGmrkYs33PT4V0fueiN6hiN4zEf3viegfiuhXEbeP/wE)

Comment: If your embedded system supports lookups against the running code's symbol table, you could code a hack by naming the variable to be the same as the query string key, and do a symbol table lookup to find the address of the associated variable.

Comment: Thank you very much!!. Really appreciate the time you put in your reply. Tbh your method looks a bit complicated to me (as a beginner) However, the method provided by CraigEstey above looks more comprehensible. Would you be able to give me a simple example on how to use this method? I tried using the strtok function and it works. It's printing the key=value separately without the &. But how can I add the key and value to a struct using strchr function?

Comment: You did not present any parsing code, so I didn't present any either. What I presented was a way to stash the values into a table indexed by an enum.

Comment: s there any keyword i can search for or a reference so I can read more about your method is this called hashing?

Comment: The `key_table` is being initialized with *designated initializers*. The enumerations can be set to hash values so that the computed hash for a key string would match a particular enumeration value, so that the lookup function can be implemented as a hash lookup.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will do my homework and read about designated initializers and hashing. I thought the solution was easy! Thanks again